# Comparing certain bits not producing desired results

Tags: c#, binary, comparison, bit-shift, bit

I have a program that takes in a text file of assembly code and parses through that and changes every line to a binary code. Each line is a separate 16 bit binary code (values are stored as UInt 16), which I then put in the array. The codes are (in integer representation):

```
32768 //
65285 //
64514 //
65280 //
64512 //
65281 //
64513 // 
36352 //
65025 //
63488 // 
58899 // 
38400 //
65024 //
64257 //
64512 //
65026 //
64258 //
61952 //
59911 //
42496 //
65026
```

Now how each code is broken up is 7 bits (instruction), 1 bit(immediate), 8 bits(value). I am now trying to parse those 3 separate sections of the binary code. I wrote the following to do that:

```
   public void doInstruction()
    {
       foreach(var op in IPE.opCodes)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("this is the original op code: " + op);
           var instr = (op >> 0) & 127;
           Console.WriteLine(instr + " THIS IS THE INSTRUCTION BINARY");
       }
    }
```

Now for example, the first code (32768 = 1000000000000000). I use the code above to compare that to the binary code of 32768 to the binary code of 127, which in my mind should produce 1000000 (64 should appear in the output). But after I run my code. My output is:

```
    this is the original op code: 32768
    0 THIS IS THE INSTRUCTION BINARY
```

When the output should be:

```
    this is the original op code: 32768
    64 THIS IS THE INSTRUCTION BINARY
```

What am I missing/doing wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift right 9 positions to get an instruction `var intsr = op >> 9;` it will contain 7 bits for instruction. Testing for immediate (1bit position 9) and value could be done using just &: `op & 256` and value `op & 255`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was doing it in the opposite way apparently, I understand how it works now. The code also runs how it should now, thanks again!